# FaceTime: Connect Mac to iPhone

Tags: iphone, mac, facetime

I just bought my first Mac, and I want to use FaceTime with someone who has an iPhone.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FaceTime is a US $1 app on the App Store. You will need to enter an AppleID into the app to send or receive calls, but the software holds your hand through this process, making a new AppleID if needed for you.

Once you have that installed and running, make sure your contact's iPhone is in the address book and dial them up.

You can call out to AppleID that are used on the Mac and iPod/iPad and you call to a "phone number" to iPhones that are in WiFi.

The nice easy support page for FaceTime on the mac is http://www.apple.com/support/mac/facetime/

A short list of hardware requirements [is here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4534).

Comment: Thanks.  So, it's **required** for the iPhone to be on WiFi?

Comment: iOS4 only allows FaceTime on iPhone when WiFi is on. iOS5 (not yet released) has been announced to let each carrier decide to allow or deny non-WiFi FaceTime. The hardware is ready, the software is expected sometime this Fall. I'm sure they are polishing the UI, but the big part is making it work with only the carriers that want to allow or bill for 3G FaceTime.